# Reinstall Mountain Lion on an older mac

Tags: macos, itunes, install

I bought a new mac and want to sell my old one. It came with Snow Leopard but I upgraded a few times since I bought it. I have deauthorized, reformatted and reinstalled OS X on my mac following the instructions here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5189

When I reinstalled, it installed Mountain Lion (not Snow Leopard) and asked me for my iTunes account to verify that I purchased Mountain Lion. I used Command-Q to quit after the install, so it is at the factory default welcome screen at the moment.

My question: if I sell it, is my iTunes account tied to the computer now since it asked for that during installation? And if so, is it possible to return it to an identity-free state to sell?

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this article this morning that might be helpful: [How to Prepare a MacBook Pro For Sale that was Upgraded to Mavericks by Scott Williams](http://blog.swilliams.me/words/2014/1/13/how-to-prepare-a-macbook-pro-for-sale-that-was-upgraded-to-mavericks)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone

Comment: It seems Scott, at that link, reinstalled Snow Leopard from the CD. And says "The catch though is that the new user needs to have an Apple ID that has already "purchased" Mavericks for the install to continue." implying (but not confirming) that the apple id provided will persist as the new users apple id.

Answer (score 1):

As to whether the Apple ID persists on the reinstalled drive using the approach I did: I don't know.

A better way is probably to install Mavericks from a USB thumb drive, described here:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=18081307&postcount=3

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app --nointeraction
```

Assuming "Install OS X Mavericks.app" is in your Applications folder and your thumbdrive is called "Untitled".

Comment: Yes - using an install media like this severs the store link and you can even set up the device without needing to join WiFi and have leakage of passwords in that instance.